Is this variant of post correspondence problem undecidable?
The post correspondence problem, as defined by wikipedia, is undecidable. The problem is defined as follows.

Let $A$ be an alphabet with at least two symbols.  The input of the problem consists of two finite lists $\alpha_{1}, \ldots, \alpha_{N}$ and $\beta_{1}, \ldots, \beta_{N}$ of words over $A$. A solution to this problem is a sequence of indices $(i_k)_{1 \leq k \leq K}$ with $K \geq 1$ and $ 1 \leq i_k \le N$ for all $k$, such that:
$$\alpha_{i_1} \ldots \alpha_{i_K} = \beta_{i_1} \ldots \beta_{i_K}.$$
The decision problem then is to decide whether such a solution exists or not.

But what happens if we additionally require the sequence to be such that each index in the solution sequence must appear a given fraction of times? More specifically, what happens if we additionally require for each index $i$ in the sequence to appear precisely $1/N$ times? Does this problem remain undecidable?
I would think that it is not sufficient to search for solutions with precisely $N$ indices, so it is not immediately obvious whether it is decidable. But on the other hand the usual reduction from the halting problem no longer holds.

This introduces the obstruction that if the sum of the lengths of $\alpha, \beta$ are different potential solutions are bounded in length.
